# Consumir Web Service WSDL con Nusoap PHP

Tags: php, java, webservice

Un saludo, 
estoy intenteando consumir un Web Service con la librería Nusoap en PHP. Ya antes la había trabajado pero para esta oportunidad es algo diferente.

Tengo un programa en Java que ya está funcionando, pero ahora necesito hacerlo desde la web, con php, si es posible.
Viendo el programa en Java, pude notar que el ws pide algún tipo de autentificación, tengo el usuario, contraseña y token, pero no sé como autenticarme con estos datos usando Nusoap. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Éste es el WS:
[Web Service](https://dpfactura.com.co/wsFact_e/InterSoap)

Éste es el código en PHP:

```
<?php
include ("lib/nusoap.php");
$wsdlIniciar = "https://dpfactura.com.co/wsFact_e/InterSoap?wsdl";

$clientIniciar=new nusoap_client($wsdlIniciar, 'wsdl');

$paramIniciar= array (
    'tokenempresa'=>'xxx',
    'usernamePt'=>'xxx',
    'passwordPt'=>'xxx',
);

$response = $clientIniciar->call('consultarEstadoFactura',$paramIniciar);

if ($clientIniciar->fault) { // si
   $error = $clientIniciar->getError();
if ($error) { // Hubo algun error
       echo 'Error:  ' . $clientIniciar->faultstring;
   }
}

echo '<hr>';
print_r($response);
echo '<hr>';
print_r($paramIniciar);
```

Y esta es la salida del error:

```
Array ( [return] => Array ( [aceptacion] => 0 [acuse] => 0 [consecutivo] => 0 [error] => Alerta! no se pudo verificar la autenticidad del cliente. [estado] => 0 [estadoAdquiriente] => 0 [estadodian] => 0 [idLote] => 0 [rechazo] => 0 ) )
```

Está es una parte del código Java:

```
private static EnvioFacturaRespuestaDTO enviarFactura(co.com.dispapeles.wsdispapeles.soap.EBfelEncabezadofactura arg0) {
    co.com.dispapeles.wsdispapeles.soap.InterSoap_Service service = new co.com.dispapeles.wsdispapeles.soap.InterSoap_Service();
    co.com.dispapeles.wsdispapeles.soap.InterSoap port = service.getInterSoapPort();

    Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
    req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://dpfactura.com.co/wsFact_e/InterSoap?wsdl");
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    headers.put("username", Collections.singletonList("XXXXXX"));
    headers.put("password", Collections.singletonList("XXXXXX"));
    headers.put("token", Collections.singletonList("XXXXXXX"));
    req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);        

    return port.enviarFactura(arg0);
}
```

Agradezco si alguien tiene idea de como hacer la autentificación. Gracias!

Comment: pudiste resolver el problema con tu web service?

Comment: Saludos, alguien pudo resolver el problema? @JorgeLeonardoCorreaMuñoz

Comment: Todavía necesitan el código?